# Xpath of element with some count

Tags: webdriver

I'm using webdrive java and testng.

I need to find the xpath or some other locator for Users(80). 80 is count of users which chnages according to users count. From IDE, i got link=Users80, but as 80 changes, i think it's not a good idea to use it as locator in my code because next time if I execute program, the count may be 30 or 90, so the locator would be Users(90) and my program would fail.

Please help me find the locator:

```
 <div>
<a href="/test2/test/public/admin/projects/project/index/project_id/1">Dashboard</a>
</div>
 </li>
  <li id="items_" class="active">
  <div>
 <a href="/test2/test/public/projects/project/visits/project_id/1" style="background-color:         transparent;">
  Users
   <span>80</span>
     </a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lot of ways to do that. Check out [this for more details](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/appendix_locating_techniques.jsp),

For given HTML, Try the following,

```
 driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Users")).click();
```

Comment: @user3241182,Glad its worked. please Up vote and accept the answer. That's how we repay in the stack overflow. (Since you are new to So site)